# Can i start activity automatically every 1 hours?

Tags: android

Now i'm making a application that every 20 seconds send data to my database server in internet. but when my activity was running until 2 hours, my application not responding and not send data again to database server.
Can i start activity automatically every 1 hours without the help of user??

Comment: use broadcast receiver to send the data and start activity from broadcast receiver.

Comment: Yes you can restart your activity with `Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);` // at periodic interval using **Timer**

Comment: can you give me a sample?? I've spent almost 3 days to complete this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use **[AlarmManager](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129)** Class or **[TimerTask](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/SchedulingaTimerTasktoRunRepeatedly.htm)** Class for such purpose. In `AlarmManager` you can schedule your activity for every hours. Same as in `TimerTask` you can schedule your Activity for every hour.

Comment: This tutorial is actually good @Lucifer, but, do you have any idea about initiating an action inside an activity, every hour??