# Instantiate a function in an activity automatically for every 24 hours in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to instantiate a function(`method1()`) from an activity(`act1.java`) automatically for every 24 hours. I have checked some other tutorials, which demonstrated the usage of TimerTask and AlarmManager. But, there I am unable to understand the flow of the code. Can any one please provide me some sample code, or tutorials, so that I can get an idea of using `TimerTask` and `AlarmManager`.

These are the tutorials I have checked -

[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794690/can-i-start-activity-automatically-every-1-hours)

[two](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/DemonstrateTimerandTimerTask.htm)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that second tutorial looks perfect, if you post what exactly you don't understand about it then we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

why not use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which is designed to schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically.

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService taskScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
 taskScheduler .scheduleAtFixedRate(yourRunnable, 0, 24, HOURS);
```

Also consider  [Quartz Scheduling](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) which is useful if you are using scheduling jobs extensively in your project. More maintainable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @M Sach, can we apply the same concept for services also? becuse, the requirements, means, now I have to instantiate that function in background as a service.

Comment: yes you can do. you can use put this code under web listener so that your code gets executed once you start your webcontainer. Otherwise you can consider Quartz scheduler.